# How to store GPS location in background on every 10mins?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, gps

How to store GPS location in background on any time, such as 5, 10 or 20mins and to store it into localStorage ? THanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add any code you have to the question.

Comment: The question is simple. I just want to store user's gps location when open my ionic app and to store that location into localStorage.

Comment: And so was mine... what have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Please explain your question, so that people who try to help you can understand it and give you a detailed answer.

Comment: start coding, use some location plugins and put your location calling api in a time interval of your choice and update that in your local storage

Comment: @SaEChowdary how to set time interval ? I've a plugin for gps.

Comment: which ionic version your using?

Comment: @SaEChowdary ionic 4

Comment: setInterval(()=> { your code here}, your time duration here);

Comment: welcome dude, next time when you ask anything please share some code, so that you will get proper solution on time

Comment: @SaEChowdary dude, where do i  need to add this code ? Into public geolocate() function or in into ionviewdidload ?

Comment: @SaEChowdary : look http://dpaste.com/14RDTDY

Comment: the code or the function which will get you the location details and stores in local storage  should be inside flower brackets of setinterval functin

Comment: Is this ok dude : http://dpaste.com/14RDTDY

Comment: no, look into my answer

Answer (score 0):

edit like this

```
public geolocate() {

    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: false,
      maximumAge: Infinity
    };

    this.geo.getCurrentPosition(options)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log("What is in this geolocate? ", resp);

        const location = { Lat: resp.coords.latitude, Lon: resp.coords.longitude };
        this.storage.set('GeoLocation', location);

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
      });
  }
```

now call this function in setinterval like below

```
setInterval(() => {
             this.geolocate();
            }, 600);
```

so that your function will called for every 600ms and excute the plugin and stores.

Comment: Something went wrong with this code : setInterval(() => {
             this.geolocate();
            }, 600);   i've got too many errors.

Comment: okay try to resolve them and this is the process for setinterval

Comment: Error in code : setInterval(() => {
  this.geolocate();
}, 50000);

Comment: how to set interval to 10mins ?

Comment: put 600000 instead of 600